# Long term Access Tokens for Dailymotion

Tags: access-token, dailymotion-api

I want to obtain long term access tokens on the server side for Dailymotion.
I have been following http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/authentication.html , but it only gives a short term access token along with a refresh token

I have implemented the same for Facebook, where I just passed the short term token in exchange for a long term one which is valid for 60 Days.

Is there a similar thing available in Dailymotion

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the website, Dailymotion only offers short term access tokens for security reasons. 
If you are using PHP,Javascript or objective-c, you should use the SDKs: access tokens management is already implemented so you don't have to care about checking token validity at every request.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since I need to query daily stats from Dailymotion through automated cron job and it's impossible to redirect to Dailymotion every time it requires authentication. How to solve this?